# Compute the number of injective mappings

Tags: combinatorics

Proof that the number of *injective* mappings of 
$A=\{a_1,a_2,a_3,\dots,a_r\}$  in $B=\{b_1,b_2,b_3,\dots,b_n\}$ 
with $r\leq n$
is 
$$n(n-1)\dots(n-r+1)=\frac{n!}{(n-r)!}.$$

Comment: It would be good to give some indication of what you've tried and where you got stuck.  (Also, the English word "application" means something different from the French "application".  The latter is better translated as "function" or "mapping" in this context.)

Answer (score 1):

Pick an element in $A$ and map it to some element in $B$. Pick the next element in $A$: to how many elements you may map it? Continue in this fashion until you exhaust the elements of $A$. For example, if $A$ had four elements, and $B$ had $5$, I could pick $5$ options for $a_1$, then $4$ options for $a_2$, since I had to avoid picking the first element I chose for $a_2$, then $3$ options for $a_3$ and finally $2$ options for $a_4$, which accounts to $5\cdot 4\cdot 3 \cdot 2=5\cdot(5-1)\cdot(5-2)\cdot (5-3)$ injections.